# How to friendly alert user of a specific browser issue?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-behavior, alerts

In my app, an user fill a password confirmation form and submit, and the page is refreshed with JS.

Because of an unresolved bug of Safari (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23735), issued in 2009, I have to tell the user to refresh the page himself.

Here's the thing : what should I tell the user in the case he uses Safari ?

I thought about :

1. **Explaining** with soft words the issue, like `"A unresolved bug in Safari prevents us from logging you in automatically - please refresh the page."`

   - *The user might be thinking "I don't care / what's that bug? / are the developer lazy?"*
2. Just inviting to refresh the page, **without further explanation**.

   - *"What kind of product is this? They can't even auto-refresh the page?"*

What do you think?

Comment: Could you tell me why you are using a pseudo login form?

Comment: @Larivact "Pseudo" is not referring to "Pseudonym", just to be clear. I'm prompting user to confirm his password in order to forward him to another page. I'll edit it to avoid confusion.

Comment: That's a fairly old version of safari. Are you sure you can't listen for the postback and issue any kind of reload? Even if the `.reload()` command doesn't work, there are other ways to refresh the page.

Comment: @DanielBrown Whatever version of Safari you'll test, the bug's still here. Anyway, there's other factors I voluntarily omitted which would have been out of subject here, and cause me to have to prompt user.

Comment: I did understand it correctly :) Just do it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission/8664680#8664680). So that you don't have to manually refresh the page, you just cancel if he hasn't confirmed his password.

Comment: @Larivact I didn't post here to discuss about a code workaround, I'd have posted it on stackoverflow if that was the case :). From now, please just consider I have to prompt user to refresh the page.

Comment: @Bigood you shouldn't have linked to the bug in the first place if don't want technical help

Comment: @Larivact My bad then, I wanted to avoid this very kind of discussion by saying this is a real unresolved Safari bug, and not some I might have created myself, so I'm not looking for technical advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this issue truly cannot be resolved, then I believe the first option is the better of the two routes, but only if you're going to provide a solution for your end user:

If there are newer versions of Safari, or browsers that work better with your application, then it may also be worth including a link to download/update those browsers so users do not have to see this message moving forward.

If possible, providing a clickable link to refresh the page would also be preferable. Less tech savvy users may not immediately be aware of how to refresh a page.

If there is not an alternative to bypass this issue, then it may be worth using a more generic "refresh" message.

Comment: They can't upgrade Safari, but can change of browser. But that's not a fatal issue, and they'll come across it once in a while : I find it a bit overkill to propose to change. And I can't provide a clickable link either because of this bug.

Comment: Finally, I think I'll go with the generic message. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to tell about the issues.
Something like the following will do.

> Please reload the page if it doesn't automatically do.

Comment: I like it, but does it induces that my code may have problems ?

Comment: I am not sure about the safari bug. But in general, telling the user about a bug doesn't do anything productive, people prefer to read as less as possible and get on with the task. Even if there was some problem with the code, we shouldn't burden the user with it.

Comment: Yep, agreed. I might be thinking too much as a developer.

Comment: Most sites said that when something has to automatic reload, or "if download does not start please click here". Not a big issue.

Comment: Also, if it is a browser bug, they probably know about it, or are accustomed to that.